# OnClickListener not functioning properly

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a button that should set all text values in the activity to null. However, the OnClickListener doesn't seem to be functioning as I would have thought.

Does the issue have to do with  me setting the text to the Prefs key after the button? I've been at this bug for awhile and can't seem to figure it out on my own.

Here's the code:

```
package com.mikitz.rogsimple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DamageChest extends Activity {

EditText chestdmg1, chestdmg2, chestdmg3, chestdmg4, chestdmg5, chestdmg6, chestdmg7, chestdmg8, chestdmg9, chestdmg10; 
Button heal;    

SharedPreferences pref;

String getChestDMG1, getChestDMG2, getChestDMG3, getChestDMG4, getChestDMG5, getChestDMG6, getChestDMG7, getChestDMG8, getChestDMG9, getChestDMG10; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.damage_chest);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    heal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fullheal);

    chestdmg1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg1);
    chestdmg2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg2);
    chestdmg3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg3);
    chestdmg4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg4);
    chestdmg5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg5);
    chestdmg6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg6);
    chestdmg7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg7);
    chestdmg8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg8);
    chestdmg9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg9);
    chestdmg10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg10);

    getChestDMG1 = pref.getString("chestdmg1", "");
    getChestDMG2 = pref.getString("chestdmg2", "");
    getChestDMG3 = pref.getString("chestdmg3", "");
    getChestDMG4 = pref.getString("chestdmg4", "");
    getChestDMG5 = pref.getString("chestdmg5", "");
    getChestDMG6 = pref.getString("chestdmg6", "");
    getChestDMG7 = pref.getString("chestdmg7", "");
    getChestDMG8 = pref.getString("chestdmg8", "");
    getChestDMG9 = pref.getString("chestdmg9", "");
    getChestDMG10 = pref.getString("chestdmg10", "");

    final OnClickListener fullheal = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {    
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
              editor.remove("chestdmg1");
              editor.remove("chestdmg2");
              editor.remove("chestdmg3");
              editor.remove("chestdmg4");
              editor.remove("chestdmg5");
              editor.remove("chestdmg6");
              editor.remove("chestdmg7");
              editor.remove("chestdmg8");
              editor.remove("chestdmg9");
              editor.remove("chestdmg10");
              editor.commit();                

              chestdmg1.setText("");
              chestdmg2.setText("");
              chestdmg3.setText("");
              chestdmg4.setText("");
              chestdmg5.setText("");
              chestdmg6.setText("");
              chestdmg7.setText("");
              chestdmg8.setText("");
              chestdmg9.setText("");
              chestdmg10.setText("");
            }
        };

    heal.setOnClickListener(fullheal); 

    chestdmg1.setText(getChestDMG1); 
    chestdmg2.setText(getChestDMG2); 
    chestdmg3.setText(getChestDMG3); 
    chestdmg4.setText(getChestDMG4); 
    chestdmg5.setText(getChestDMG5); 
    chestdmg6.setText(getChestDMG6); 
    chestdmg7.setText(getChestDMG7); 
    chestdmg8.setText(getChestDMG8); 
    chestdmg9.setText(getChestDMG9); 
    chestdmg10.setText(getChestDMG10); 



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();                    
        editor.putString("chestdmg1", chestdmg1.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg2", chestdmg2.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg3", chestdmg3.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg4", chestdmg4.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg5", chestdmg5.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg6", chestdmg6.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg7", chestdmg7.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg8", chestdmg8.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg9", chestdmg9.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("chestdmg10", chestdmg10.getText().toString());

        editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(this, "GREAT SUCCESS!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent (this, DamageTracker.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?

Comment: Can you show the layout xml ?

Comment: Try to write your `onClickListener` code outside your `onCreate` method.

Comment: What does "not functioning properly" actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi why not use like this

```
heal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
          editor.putString("chestdmg1", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg2", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg3", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg4", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg5", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg6", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg7", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg8", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg9", "");
          editor.putString("chestdmg10", "");
          editor.commit();                

        }
    });
```

It's quietly simple. if you use `pref.edit()` it's look like you at mode update or save.
let's see [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Because the EditText is saved right back into Pref once I hit the back button negating the onClick method

Comment: I don't absolutely know what's your meaning. you want to save the preferences with heal button. after that you click back button, and the preferences is back, that is your meaning? if to be like that you must try [Task and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) or [activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) on lauchMode

Answer (score 0):

change the activity to

```
public class DamageChest extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

then put the following code in your class

```
heal.setOnClickListener(this);
```

override the onclick to the class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.fullheal:
    // do your code here
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
          editor.remove("chestdmg1");
          editor.remove("chestdmg2");
          editor.remove("chestdmg3");
          editor.remove("chestdmg4");
          editor.remove("chestdmg5");
          editor.remove("chestdmg6");
          editor.remove("chestdmg7");
          editor.remove("chestdmg8");
          editor.remove("chestdmg9");
          editor.remove("chestdmg10");
          editor.commit();                

          chestdmg1.setText("");
          chestdmg2.setText("");
          chestdmg3.setText("");
          chestdmg4.setText("");
          chestdmg5.setText("");
          chestdmg6.setText("");
          chestdmg7.setText("");
          chestdmg8.setText("");
          chestdmg9.setText("");
          chestdmg10.setText("");
   break;
   default:

   break;
}
```

check by this way and let me know if it would not work

Comment: results in this error: `The type DamageChest must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)`

Comment: please remove the onclick method your have created manually. and go to your class name and implement the method given in the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

xml code:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickbtn"
    android:text="Button2" />
```

in Your Activity code :

```
public void onClickbtn(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button2:
        // put you code here
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
   }
```

Comment: results in this error: `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 - void is an invalid type for the variable heal
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected` over "heal" on this line: `public void heal (View v) {`